# How do I add data from two files together?

Tags: python, file, text-files

I am making a calorie counting program in python, and the program creates two text files, one for food calories consumed and one for exercises calories burned, I need to subtract the burned calories from food calories, but the info for both are in separate text files, how do I create another text file and add the data from these two into it?

I have tried having the files in functions that return their data, then adding the adding the functions so the calories expended can be subtracted from calories consumed, but it seems functions cannot be added or concatenated.

`Excercise.txt` is created above in some other block of code, and entering excercise hours is as well, which were omitted to retain simplicity here. This block reads, adds, and displays the code in the shell for exercises.

```
def liftnumber():
    total=0
    products=[]
    file = open("excercises.txt", "r")
    for line in file: #put data from file int6o propdytc list
        products.append(line)
    file.close()


    for item in products: # show products
        currentline = item.split(",") #split data where tyhe is a comma
        total=total+int(currentline[0])
    print("Total calories expended:",total*100)
```

This block of code adds all the food calories together in `inventory.txt`, and this code block also follows along the lines of the last one, where inventory.txt and entering the food is created somewhere else. The only difference is that this one has 2 data snippets separated by commas; the calories and the food name, whereas the last one has one snippet: exercise hours

```
def finishday():
    total=0
    print("HERE'S HOW YOU DID TODAY")
    print("-----------------")
    products=[] ##create a list that holds all foods from inventory.txt
    file = open("inventory.txt", "r")
    for line in file: #put data from file int6o propdytc list
        products.append(line)
    file.close()

    for item in products: # show products
        currentline = item.split(",") #split data where tyhe is a comma
        total=total+int(currentline[1])

    print("Total calories consumed:",total)

    liftnumber()
```

If you can't replicate the problem with the code above, try the whole program below:

Function to allow the user to make a choice off main loop:

```
def mainmenu():
    print("------------------------")
    print("ETCHAPP")
    print("------------------------")
    print("1> enter a new food")
    print("2> see foods")
    print("3> delete something")
    print("4> enter excercises")
    print("5> finish day")
    print("6> see excercises")

    print("x> exit program")
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    choice=choice.strip()
    return(choice)

def enterproduct():
    print("ENTER A NEW FOOD")
    print("------------------------")
    number=input("enter food: ")

    price=input("enter calories in food consumed: ")

    # should remove any leading or trailing spaces
    number = number.strip()
    price = price.strip()

    # write data to the file as one line (comma delimited)
    line =number+","+price+"\n" #put all the data together
    with open("inventory.txt","a") as file:
        file.write(line) #write product data
    file.close()


def seeproducts():
    print("REPORT OF PRODUCTS")
    print("-----------------")
    products=[] #create a list that holds all foods from inventory.txt
    file = open("inventory.txt", "r")
    for line in file: #put data from file into propdytc list
        products.append(line)
    file.close()

    for item in products: # show prioducts
        print(item)
        currentline = item.split(",") #split data where there is a comma
        prodnumber = currentline[0]
        price = currentline[1]

# This one allows user to enter excercise times
def enterlift():
    print("ENTER A NEW EXCERCISE")
    print("------------------------")
    print("(must be 30 bpm over normal heart rate)")
    num=input("enter number of hours excercised: ")

    # should remove any leading or trailing spaces
    num = num.strip()

    # write data to the file as one line (comma delimited)
    line =num+"\n" #put all the data together
    with open("excercises.txt","a") as file:
        file.write(line) #write product data
    file.close()

# This one adds all the excercise times together
def liftnumber():
    total=0
    products=[] #create a list that holds all foods from inventory.txt
    file = open("excercises.txt", "r")
    for line in file: #put data from file int6o propdytc list
        products.append(line)
    file.close()


    for item in products: # show products
        currentline = item.split(",") #split data where tyhe is a comma
        total=total+int(currentline[0])
    print("Total calories expended:",total*100)



# This one allows user to see excercise times entered
def seelift():
    print("HERE'S HOW YOU'RE DOING")
    print("-----------------")

    total=0
    products=[] #create a list that holds all foods from inventory.txt
    file = open("excercises.txt", "r")
    for line in file: #put data from file int6o propdytc list
        products.append(line)
    file.close()

    for item in products: # show products
        currentline = item.split(",") #split data where tyhe is a comma
        total=total+int(currentline[0])
    print("Total hours excercised:",total)
    print("Total calories expended:",total*100)

# This finishes a day and begins the next one
def finishday():
    total=0
    print("HERE'S HOW YOU DID TODAY")
    print("-----------------")
    products=[] #create a list of which weill hold all products from the 
file inventory.txt
    file = open("inventory.txt", "r")
    for line in file: #put data from file int6o propdytc list
        products.append(line)
    file.close()

    for item in products: # show products
        currentline = item.split(",") #split data where tyhe is a comma
        total=total+int(currentline[1])

    print("Total calories consumed:",total)

    liftnumber()

#This deletes things
def deleteproduct():
    products=[] #create a list whcih will hold all products from file 
inventory.txt
    currentindex=0 #this will be use4d to get an index
    #position od utem to delete in list
    file = open("inventory.txt","r")
    for line in file: #put data frpom file into product
        products.append(line)
    file.close()
    seeproducts() #show all the products
    #enter product number to delete
    deletethis=input("Enter name of the food to delete: ")

    #loop through produces find matching number
    #delete product from list
    for item in products: #show products
        currentline = item.split(",") #split data where comma
        prodnumber = currentline[0] #get the item's product number
        if prodnumber==deletethis:
            break #found product to delete
        currentindex=currentindex+1 #increment index for next product
    del products[currentindex] #delete product at this index

    #erase provios file
    file = open('inventory.txt','r+')
    file.truncate(0)

    #write new file from list
    for item in products:
        with open("inventory.txt","a") as file:
            file.write(item) #write product data
    file.close()


#main program starts here
choice=""
while choice!="x": #loop to allows user to choice
    #exit when the user chooses 'x'

    choice=mainmenu()
    if choice=="1":
        enterproduct()
    if choice=="2":
        seeproducts()
    if choice=="3":
        deleteproduct()
    if choice=="5":
        finishday()
    if choice=="4":
        enterlift()
    if choice=="6":
        seelift()
```

Expected:

I expected to have a new file created 'totalcal.txt' and to have the contents of 'inventory.txt' (only the food calorie numbers, not the food names) and 'excercises.txt' added together (sorry if this seems confusing, but by "added togther," I meant I wanted the exercise calories burned calories to be *subtracted* from the food calories consumed) and put it into a function that shows this by printing the "total calories burned to consumed" and have the number either be a negative (if the burn is more than the calories consumed) or a positive (if the calories consumed is more than the burn)

I would call this function inside of finishday() near the end below the calling of liftnumber()

Above is how I think it might be done, but if you can achieve the result below in some other way, I would also greatly appreciate it.

So the exact expected output is:

Here's how you did today
..........................

Total calories consumed: number1
Total calories expended: number2
Total calories burned or consumed: number1 - number2
..........................

Reality:

I forgot the exact error, but it gives me an error about not being able to add functions together based on how I tried to solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try formatting this question a bit more? It's kind of crazy right now!

Comment: Can you reformulate your question properly? Normally you read data from both files, manipulate data and then save to file. Your question and code is too long to be tested and we do not have input files. Can you emphasize the function(s) that are not returning/elaborating the result as expected?

Comment: Never mind, ignore the message above, I just want to know how to add two text files together in python to create a new text file with data from both files.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick Google search and found you can add two text files (or more) by doing this:

```
filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

So I figured it out, I also managed to do the subtraction to get the total calories by making a new function and returning the data, this allowed me to use the function itself as a singular piece of data however I like, which allowed me to solve the problem.

Sorry about my jumbled question, but I have it figured out now.

Thanks